# Python tuple vs generator

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, iterator, tuples

I am having a problem understanding why one of the following line returns generator and another tuple.

How exactly and why a generator is created in the second line, while in the third one a tuple is produced?

```
sample_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
generator = (i for i in sample_list)
tuple_ = (1, 2, 3, 4)

print type(generator)
<type 'generator'>

print type(tuple_)
<type 'tuple'>
```

Is it because tuple is immutable object and when I try to unpack list inside `()`, it can't create the tuple as it has to change the tuple tuple.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can imagine tuples as being created when you hardcode the values, while generators are created where you provide a way to create the objects.

This works since there is no way `(1,2,3,4)` could be a generator. There is nothing to generate there, you just specified all the elements, not a rule to obtain them.

In order for your `generator` to be a tuple, the expression `(i for i in sample_list)` would have to be a tuple comprehension. There is no way to have tuple comprehensions, since comprehensions require a mutable data type.

Thus, the syntax for what should have been a tuple comprehension has been reused for generators.

Comment: Actually there is tuple comprehension: `xs = [1, 2, 3]; ys = tuple(x for x in xs); type(ys)`

Comment: @visitor That's not a tuple comprehension. `x for x in xs` is a generator, and this is then *converted* to a `tuple`.

Answer (score 7):

Parentheses are used for three different things: grouping, tuple literals, and function calls. Compare `(1 + 2)` (an integer) and `(1, 2)` (a tuple). In the `generator` assignment, the parentheses are for grouping; in the `tuple` assignment, the parentheses are a tuple literal. Parentheses represent a tuple literal when they contain a comma and are not used for a function call.

Comment: I under `(1+2)` is int and `(1, 2)` would be function call, what i don't understand is what you mean by in the generator assignment.

Comment: @GaurangShah: When you’re assigning `generator = …`. `… for … in …` is a generator when it’s inside parentheses.