# Is it possible to delete a repetitive things of an element in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list that I queried from MySQL server that contains something similar to example below but way more elements in it. For some reasons it has extra commas and brackets.

`[(datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 1, 14),), (datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 1, 33, 50),)]`

Is there a way to eliminate specific brackets and comas that will produce

```
[datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 1, 14), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 1, 33, 50)]
```

When I print the first element in the list it shows

```
(datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 1, 14),)
```

Where I want it to be

```
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 1, 14)
```

I can't seem to know where to look for this solution or how to even search for this problem. Any advice?

Comment: Looks like you've got a list of tuples and you want to only print the first element. Suppose the result of your query is stored in the variable `myResult`, you could do: `print(myResult[0][0])` or loop over all of the results: `for result in myResult: print(result[0])`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  In particular, post the problem code: there is no output from what you showed us.

Comment: @pault Amazing! Now i have a different output. Any idea how does this happen. As in when i call just `print(myResult)` it prints all the datetime.datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your query is returning a `list` of `tuple`s:

```
myResult = [
    (datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 1, 14),),
    (datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 1, 33, 50),)
]
```

You could access the first element of the first tuple by doing:

```
print(myResult[0][0])
#datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 1, 14)
```

Here the first `[0]` refers to index 0 of the list `myResult` and the second `[0]` refers to index 0 of the tuple `myResult[0]`.

Or you can modify `myResult` using a list comprehension to get the first element:

```
print([result[0] for result in myResult])
#[datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 1, 14), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 1, 33, 50)]
```

This isn't a bug, but rather it's a display issue. The reason that it's displaying as `(some_value,)` instead of `(some_value)` is because without the `,` at the end, you wouldn't have a `tuple` but rather a generator expression.

Read more here: [Python tuple vs. generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45849120/python-tuple-vs-generator).

Answer (score 2):

It's returning a list of tuples, each tuple containing what you were querying for. You only queried for one field, so each of your tuples contained 1 item. To flatten this, I'd use a simple list comprehension:

```
flattened = [x[0] for x in result]
```

Where `result` is your original list.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to clean up your list, by taking the first element in each list.

Using your example list:

```
dirty = [(datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 1, 14),), (datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 1, 33, 50),)]
```

You want to take the first element in each list:

```
clean = [i[0] for i in dirty]
```

Calling:

```
clean[0]
```

produces:

```
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 1, 14)
```